# Keycloak secured service returns HTTP status 302 when tried to be accessed with Keycloak token

Tags: rest, http, token, keycloak, http-status-code-302

I have a very simple REST service secured with Keycloak. I get a keycloak token and try to access this REST service but get an HTTP 302 status. Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: 302 status is a redirect. Where is it redirecting to?

Comment: Look at response headers for the 302. What is the value of Location header?

Answer (score 0):

302 is perfectly correct, you are being redirected back to your application after logging in. If you see an empty page or if you were expecting something else, you might want to check the console of your browser (for example you might be having a CORS issue)